# How to redisplay div (Highchart) after Ajax update

Tags: ajax, jsf, highcharts

I have a Highcharts working fine, and Primefaces PanelGrid working fine, but i need refresh or update or recall Higcharts with update event of button.

The code:

```
<h:panelGrid id="pnlStatus" columns="2" >
            <p:editor id="txtStatus" height="400" value="#{Reports.emailTxt}" style="width: 100%" />

            <div id="chartEmailReport" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
</h:panelGrid>

        <p:commandButton update="pnlStatus" value="Ver reporte" icon="ui-icon-document"
                         actionListener="#{Reports.emailStatusReport}"/>
```

When i press the commandButton the Highcharts just disappear...

I need redisplay Higcharts with any event of commandButton.

Update: The same happens with a plain jsf `h:commandButton` with an `f:ajax` inside it but not with out ajax, so it seems ajax related

Iam noob sorry for my English...

Comment: I don't see any highcharts here... and does it work with an normal jsf commandbutton and ajax?

Comment: This             <div id="chartEmailReport" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
is a Highcharts... and it is a Primefaces commandButton (ajax).

Comment: It is a plain div in your code, no highcharts script or anything visible. And read my question. Try with a normal jsf button with ajax

Comment: Yes highcharts script work fine, only need re call the plain div... AH ok, now y try with normal jsf button, thanks...

Comment: normal jsf button work fine: <h:commandButton update="pnlStatus" value="Ver reporte" icon="ui-icon-document"
                             actionListener="#{Reports.emailStatusReport}"
                             onstart="PF('statusDialog').show()" onsuccess="PF('statusDialog').hide()" > 

but how to add ajax for this? the button refresh the page not the panel... thanks!

Comment: Put an ajax tag inside it (using google helps)

Comment: Yes i know, but when use ajax, highcharts disappear without ajax highcharts is recalled and work fine! 
With primefaces and jsf button same problem. Another idea?

Comment: So your actual problem is how to update highchart after an ajax update... not PrimeFaces commandbutton related but eneric ajax.Knowing that narrows down the problem and makes it easier to find a solution. Still not clear how the div becomes a chart. Find that out...

Comment: In html file use: <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div> to draw the Highcharts.

In js file the chart script.

E.g. http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/

My problem is when i press primefaces commandButton the Highcarts disappear (using ajax) without ajax this commandButton refresh all page and the chart is recalled... I need work this same but using ajax to refresh panel instansed of all page. More clear? Thanks!

Comment: Yes I know what the problem is, but in **your** code there is nothing visible that makes the div into a highchart. In the jsfiddle there is. So your code is either wrong or not a [mcve]. If you do have the js in your page, the js is ONLY applied once, not on/after the ajax request. See all the 'related' questions on the right of this question. Lots and lots of info there if you just narrow down the problem and get to grips with the basics of webdevelopment, jsf and the components.

Comment: see also http://www.highfaces.org/

Comment: No, in my html i have     <script src="resources/js/chartEmailReport.js"></script>
And the js file y the correct folder. You need view js file code?

Comment: no, inspect it yourself, see how it works and analyse when things are applied and how to reapply them again.

Comment: Very similar to Highcharts.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
<script src="resources/js/chartEmailReport.js">
```

Use the Omnifaces [onLoadScript](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/onloadScript) tag

I have my javascript inline within the .xhtml file so it looks like this:

```
<o:onloadScript>
       var chart1= new Highcharts.Chart( {
         chart: {
           renderTo: 'rollupId:rollup'
         }
       ...
        series :  #{controller.chartData} 
    } );

</o:onloadScript>
```

perhaps you can do

```
<o:onloadScript>
   <h:outputScript name="js/chartEmailReport.js" />
</o:onloadScript>
```

Then when you click a commandButton to update your JSF components, the onloadScript will also trigger an update on your javascript